# No context type was found in the assembly - The type 'ApplicationDbContext' does not inherit from DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When I am trying to update the database It is throwing the following error. Please note that update-database cmd used to work fine with me before.

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Tycoon'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

I have tried Enable-Migrations but when I do that I get the following error.

> No context type was found in the assembly 'Tycoon'.

And then I tried this

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName <YOUR_PROJECT_NAME> -ContextTypeName <YOUR_CONTEXT_NAME>
```

but got the following error.

> The type 'ApplicationDbContext' does not inherit from DbContext. The DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextType property must be set to a type that inherits from DbContext

I am building MVC application with Individual User accounts hence `ApplicationDbContext` class was created by default which is inherited from  `IdentityDbContext`.

Please note that I was able to do migrations before but I am not sure why is it throwing errors now.

Comment: If you've moved your `DbContext` out of the top level MVC App, then remember to select the assembly containing the `DbContext` before running `Update-Database` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the name for your context file is ApplicationDbContext, try deriving it from base class DbContext as:

`public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext`